# Change an Audio Windows Setting (from the Settings App) via code

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

It's the second day I've been trying to design a simple shell that allows me to quickly switch between stereo audio with my headphones and mono audio with my amplifier. This seemingly simple operation is apparently impossible to program for some bizarre reason.

Anyway, I managed to find a good program to switch the default device but I can't find a way to change the **Accessibility** setting that allows me to switch between mono and stereo audio. I've tried changing the registry and forcing a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message but that didn't work either. I'm at a complete loss.

So I'd like to ask if anyone knows a way to do this?

Better yet, what is the function that the **Settings App** calls when you click the little switch to change from mono to stereo and vice-versa? Logically, if I make a program that calls that function it should work.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the AccessibilityMonoMixState registry value from Windows 10 Creators Update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I briefly looked on MSDN and could not find anything in the Win32 documentation. It might be a WinRT/UWP only API or simply undocumented.

As a last resort you can [set the AccessibilityMonoMixState registry value and restart the audio service](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/101006-turn-off-mono-audio-windows-10-a.html).